# RaspberryPiからiSDIOコマンドでHTTP GETをしたい

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, flashair

TOSHIBAのFlashairの利用例では、Flashairをサーバにしてファイルをダウンロードするというものばかりですが、iSDIOという機能を使うとHTTPClientにもなれるみたいです。
なのでRaspberryPiをFlashairにインストールし、RaspberryPiからisDIOコマンドで別のサーバからHTTP GETでファイルをダウンロードしたいと思っています。

iSDIOコマンドを使うためには、SDカード(Flashair)に対して生コマンド(CMD48/49)を送る必要があるようなんですが、そういえばLinuxからSDカードにどうやって生コマンドを送るんだと。
通常のファイル操作と競合しないのかという心配もあります。
ioctl()で生コマンドを送れるのがベストですが、ドライバの改造が必要なら、カーネルソースのこの辺を見ろとか、何か取っ掛かりになる情報を持っている方がいればよろしくお願いします。
実例がのっている参考文献の紹介とかも歓迎です。

**追記**
質問の内容がちょっとまずかったと思うので補足します。

RaspberryPiでは3だとWiFiモジュールがオンボードで搭載されていますし、3以外でもUSB接続のWiFiドングルなりを接続すればいいだけなので、意図が伝わりづらかったと思いますが、
ようはiSDIOをLinuxで叩いている情報が調べた限り見当たらなかったので参考情報が何かないかを聞きたかったのです。
RaspberryPiを例として出したのは、手軽に試せる組込みLinux環境だからであって、WiFiドライバを積んでいないような、最小限の組込みLinuxでもFlashAirでWiFi接続できるようになるのが最終目的です。この場合、オンボードのSDスロットがSPI接続されているということはまずないので、SPI接続ならできるよ、というのも困ります。

Answer (score 1):

以下のチュートリアル内に, サンプルコードがあり「iSDIOドライバー」が含まれています。

FlashAir組み込み機器の開発 [組み込み機器開発の概要](https://flashair-developers.github.io/website/docs/discover/device.html)

- Intelligent SDIO    [iSDIOによる制御](https://flashair-developers.github.io/website/docs/api/isdio)

  - Raspberry Pi向けチュートリアル   [インターネット同時接続モードの設定](https://flashair-developers.github.io/website/docs/tutorials/raspberrypi/1.html)

iSDIOドライバの初期化: `iSDIO_Init` を含む各種 API から `iSDIOREG_read_ext_reg` / `iSDIOREG_write_ext_reg` を呼び出し, その中で 48/49, 58/59 の `ioctl`を行っています。
そのまま使えるのではないかな？と。

そのほかに, [mmc-utils](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/cjb/mmc-utils.git/tree/mmc_cmds.c) というパッケージがあり, その中で `ioctl` を使いコマンドを発行している例もあります。

Answer (score 0):

RaspberryPiではGPIO経由でSPIが利用できます．
以下の文章はArduino向けですが，SPIを利用しているので参考になりそうです．

"FlashAir Developers - ドキュメント - Arduinoチュートリアル - iSDIO拡張コマンドの作成" https://flashair-developers.com/ja/documents/tutorials/arduino/2/

Comment: 補足します。
RaspberryPiのSDカードスロットを使って、iSDIOコマンドを発行したいのです。

Answer (score -1):

以下の記事が参考になるのではないでしょうか。

[Raspberry PiでFlashAirを動かしてみよう](https://flashair-developers.com/ja/documents/tutorials/users/1/)

Comment: その記事はRaspberryPiが起動できるFlashAirをRaspberryPi自身で作る、というだけで、本質問のiSDIO等に関しては一切言及されていないようです。参考になる、と言うには遠いかと。